# Selenium remotewebdriver timeout should (in this case) return true

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, htmlunit, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium remotewebdriver with htmlunit and have a small collection of target URLs that I need to fetch through an IPS - some of the URLs should trigger IPS to blackhole the traffic, in which case, the correct "pass" scenario for that particular test is that the request should time out.  These are in Java, btw.  So, something like this:

```
@Test
public void TESTING_IPS_THIS_SHOULD_TRIGGER_ALERT_AND_BLACKHOLE() {
    driver.get("http://testmyids.com");
    //I would like to do a simple assert here that timeout is true;

}
```

So my question is - what is the most simplistic way to achieve this in a manner more akin to assertTrue that driver timeout occurred?

Comment: What happens when it times out? I'm assuming an exception is thrown? In that case, just add a `try-catch()` and catch the expected exception. Inside that catch add an `Assert.Pass()` else `Assert.Fail()`.

Comment: Are you using JUnit or TestNG or ? You should add a tag for that and add a tag for Java.

Comment: Thanks JeffC - using JUnit, and tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of timeout WebDriver throws a [TimeoutException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html). To check if this actually happens, simply declare to expect this exception in the annotation of your test method like this:

```
@Test(expected = org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException.class)
public void TESTING_IPS_THIS_SHOULD_TRIGGER_ALERT_AND_BLACKHOLE() {
    driver.get("http://testmyids.com");
    //I would like to do a simple assert here that timeout is true;

}
```

If the exception is thrown, the test will pass. If not, the error message is:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:
>   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much, works like a charm - just set reasonable driver timeout for these tests and this is perfect.

Comment: @Flahatenrod Glad to know. In this case you may accept and upvote the answer by clicking on the arrows on the left, next to the answer. You even earn reputation by doing so because this is the preferred way at Stackoverflow to mark useful answers.